# How to use onBlur event on Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, onblur

How do you detect an onBlur event in Angular2?
I want to use it with

```
<input type="text">
```

Can anyone help me understand how to use it?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Use `(eventName)` while binding event to DOM, basically `()` is used for event binding. Also, use `ngModel` to get two-way binding for `myModel` variable.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" (blur)="onBlurMethod()">
```

**Code**

```
export class AppComponent { 
  myModel: any;
  constructor(){
    this.myModel = '123';
  }
  onBlurMethod(){
   alert(this.myModel) 
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/V7Br0vu9GPA2NmjjwVad?p=preview)

---

*Alternative 1*

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="myModel" (ngModelChange)="myModel=$event">
```

---

*Alternative 2* (not preferable)

```
<input type="text" #input (blur)="onBlurMethod($event.target.value)">
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zgNuv0UBH48Ms1EzM478?p=preview)

---

For a model-driven form to fire validation on `blur`, you could pass `updateOn` parameter.

```
ctrl = new FormControl('', {
   updateOn: 'blur', //default will be change
   validators: [Validators.required]
});
```

[**Design Docs**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dlJjRXYeuHRygryK0XoFrZNqW86jH4wobftCFyYa1PA/edit#)

Comment: Why is the alternative not preferable?

Comment: Angular does not want you using the $event inside of the HTML to send back to the JS.  All DOM operations should be done through things such as bindings, ngModel and whatnot.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use **(focusout)** event:

Use `(eventName)` for while binding event to DOM, basically `()` is used for event binding. Also you can use `ngModel` to get two way binding for your `model`. With the help of `ngModel` you can manipulate `model` variable value inside your `component`.

**Do this in HTML file**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" (focusout)="someMethodWithFocusOutEvent($event)">
```

**And in your (component) .ts file**

```
export class AppComponent { 
 model: any;
 constructor(){ }

 /*
 * This method will get called once we remove the focus from the above input box
 */
 someMethodWithFocusOutEvent() {
   console.log('Your method called');
   // Do something here
 }
}
```

Comment: @Aniketkale If I put an alert in your method `someMethodWithFocusOutEvent` the program enters into a loop as the alert makes the field lose its focus, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

you can use directly **(blur)** event in input tag.

```
<div>
   <input [value]="" (blur)="result = $event.target.value" placeholder="Type Something">
   {{result}}
</div>
```

and you will get output in "**result**"

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<input name="email" placeholder="Email"  (blur)="$event.target.value=removeSpaces($event.target.value)" value="">
```

**TS**

```
removeSpaces(string) {
 let splitStr = string.split(' ').join('');
  return splitStr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Another possible alternative**

*HTML Component file:*

```
<input formControlName="myInputFieldName" (blur)="onBlurEvent($event)">
```

*TypeScript Component file:*

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class MyEditComponent implements OnInit {

    public myForm: FormGroup;
    
    constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
    
    ngOnInit() {

        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            
            myInputFieldName: ['initial value', { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100), anotherValidator], updateOn: 'blur' }],

        });
    }

    onBlurEvent(event) {
        
        // implement here what you want

        if (event.currentTarget && event.currentTarget.value && event.currentTarget.value !== '') { }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*for reich text editor */
  public options: Object = {
    charCounterCount: true,
    height: 300,
    inlineMode: false,
    toolbarFixed: false,
    fontFamilySelection: true,
    fontSizeSelection: true,
    paragraphFormatSelection: true,

    events: {
      'froalaEditor.blur': (e, editor) => { this.handleContentChange(editor.html.get()); }}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proposed answer on the Github repo:

```
// example without validators
const c = new FormControl('', { updateOn: 'blur' });

// example with validators
const c= new FormControl('', {
   validators: Validators.required,
   updateOn: 'blur'
});
```

[Github : feat(forms): add updateOn blur option to FormControls](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/18408)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use (focusout) instead of (blur)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this in Angular 14

```
<form name="someForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)"> ...
<input
 matInput
 type="email"
 name="email"
 autocomplete="email"
 placeholder="EMAIL"
 [ngModel]="payload.email"
  #email="ngModel"
  (blur)="checkEmailBlur(f)"
  required
  email
  tabindex="1"
  autofocus
 />
```

then ... in .ts

```
 checkEmailBlur(f: NgForm) {
     const email = f.value.email;
```