# Binding a function to an invalid input FormControl in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

**Summary**

I am creating a `FormControl` with a validation pattern. When the pattern is invalid I want to call a function that will display the error message associated with the error that is being thrown.

**Example**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.personalForm = new FormGroup({
            email : new FormControl(this.auth.user.email,Validators.required ),
            first_name: new FormControl(null,[
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü']{1,30}$")
            ]),
        });
    }
```

Function to call when input field is not valid.

```
showError();
```

**Question**

Is it possible to call a function if the error is thrown and retrieve the error when an input field is not valid?

Answer (score 1):

Use either `statusChanges` (valid or invalid) or `valueChanges` event of the `FormGroup` to do this:

```
this.personalForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).subscribe((data) => {
  if (!this.personalForm.valid) {
    this.showError();
  }
}
```

Comment: is statusChanges or valueChanges in the docs somewhere I can read about? Basically when a user leaves the input field I want to call a function if there is an error.

Comment: They are here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html

To do things when user leaves an input field, you may need to look into `blur` event (something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918198/how-to-use-onblur-event-on-angular2)

Comment: Hey I appreciate you trying to help me. But this really is not working for me. Would you please break this down a little more so I understand it. I have been struggling with this since yesterday.