# Quill editor not firing (change) event in Angular

Tags: angular, quill, angular5

I'm using Quill editor with the ngx-quill NPM package. Everything is working great except that I just can't get the (change) event to fire. Here's the HTML:

```
<quill-editor (change)="validateChange(field)" [formControlName]="field.id" [id]="field.id"></quill-editor>
```

The (change)="validateChange(field)" is having no effect.

Thanks for any ideas!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In model driven form you could use `valueChanges` Observable on your form.

```
this.formName.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
   console.log('Changed Values', data)
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly for listening to changes Pankaj, thank you! 

How to I detect the blur event -- so it's firing now every time I change anything in the editor, but how about if I need to see when the user finishes updating and leaves the editor?

Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: @Matt Can you please check [How to use onBlur event on Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34918214/2435473)

Answer (score -1):

If the developer doesn't want to use reactiveForms the output event can be captured with:

```
<quill-editor (**onContentChanged**)="somefunction($event)" ></quill-editor>
```