# Angular blur input

Tags: javascript, angular

I'd like to "blur" (or unfocus, etc.) an input element from a controller.

I have reference to the input `@ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput: ElementRef`

This works:

`this.searchInput.nativeElement.focus()`

But this doesn't appear to:

`this.searchInput.nativeElement.blur()`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't attach the blur in your markup? `<input (blur)="blurHandler()" />` Here is a great link for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918198/how-to-use-onblur-event-on-angular2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Pearman that's good for handle blur events, I actually want to trigger one

Comment: Can you show the context where you call `this.searchInput.nativeElement.blur()`?

Comment: Your code should work, as long as it is called when the element is present in the DOM. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxenxn).

Comment: If you want to make one way that you can use in all inputs fields in your solution you can use Decorator @HostListener ('mouseout'). You can see more about this in this [Link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/custom-directives/hostlistener-and-hostbinding/ "@HostListener and @HostBinding") below ! https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/custom-directives/hostlistener-and-hostbinding/

Answer (score 4):

In Angular 5+ Renderer has been deprecated, and Renderer2 doesn't have the `invokeElementMethod`, but your example should work.  The only thing I can think of without seeing more of your code is you didn't add the template reference to your input in the markup:

**Template**

```html
<input #myInput id="example" name="example" formControlName="example ...>
```

**Controller**

```js
@ViewChild('myInput') public myInput: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

// ...

public onSubmit() {
  this.myInput.nativeElement.blur();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can try using [Renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer#invokeElementMethod), Inject Renderer in your component and call the code below when you want to blur

```
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'blur', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to use

```
this.renderer.selectRootElement(nativeElement).dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
```